# nullmailer swaps sender and recipient

Tags: email, debian, smtp

I want to send emails from my server through external mail server. So I installed `nullmailer` as one of simpliest MTA in Debian 7 x32.

My `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`:

```
smtp.example.com smtp --user=sender@example.com --pass=*** --port 465 --ssl
```

*user* in this case is registered user on remote server.

Now I want to send a test mail. Nullmailer replacement for sendmail has several parameters:

> usage: sendmail [flags] [recipients]
>
> -f         Set the envelope sender address

OK, so I send the mail with:

```
ls | sendmail -f sender@example.com  recipient@example.com
```

But this mail come to sender@example.com mailbox. One of headers says:

> To: undisclosed-recipients:;

As I understand nullmailer doesn't send recipient address.

OK, Now I try to send it through `php`:

```
mail("recipient@example.com","subject","message","From: sender@example.com");
```

But nothing sent in fact. The log says:

> smtp: Failed: 553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth
>   user. Sending failed:  Permanent error in sending the message

Hmm ... looks strange. If I list nullmailer queue I see

```
sendmail -bp

2015-03-23 14:58:26 332 bytes from <root@example.com>
  to <sender@example.com>
```

I don't know from where this `root@example.com` came.
So queue is frozen now. I 've found the queue in `/var/spool/nullmailer/queue/`. Each email saved as file with header and message body. A file looks like:

```
root@example.com
sender@example.com

Received: (nullmailer pid 14630 invoked by uid 0);
Mon, 23 Mar 2015 04:58:26 -0000 
To: recipient@example.com 
Subject: subject 
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:test.php 
From: sender@example.com Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2015 14:58:26 +1000 Message-Id: 1427086706.909885.14629.nullmailer@example.com>

message
```

So I changed the header from

```
root@example.com 
sender@example.com
```

to

```
sender@example.com
recipient@example.com
```

And voila! - the email was sent as expected - from `sender@example.com` to `recipient@example.com`

So my question - what I did wrong and how can I send email with `nullmailer` in normal way?

Comment: Can you post **alll** mail.log lines after you send email via sendmail?

Comment: After trying to send mail log contains only 2 lines I posted above. As I understand `nullmailer` cannot send email to `recipient@example.com` and it send it back to `root@example.com ` as error log. If I see the message file in queue - it not contains recepient address (Cc: recipient list not shown: ;) and it can be a problem why original mail was not sent

Comment: When you invoke `ls | sendmail -f sender@example.com  recipient@example.com` it will fail and nullmailer send the bounce to you right? Can you post the content of email (header + body) of the bounce?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `/etc/nullmailer/allmailfrom` answer to this, found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505750/why-is-nullmailer-appending-my-hostname-to-the-recipient-address) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124620/what-simpler-mail-server-can-i-use-instead-of-postfix) is a way to override this issue.